# How do I disable automatic display search?

Tags: xorg, linux-mint, monitors

I have a Mint 10, based on Ubuntu Maverick Meerkat (10.10) installed on a HP nc6120 notebook. The machine is getting tired, so I decided to use it only with the external "monitor", in this case, the TV. I went to the display settings, turned the notebook display off, the TV on, saved it as default and set it.

But.

Somewhy and somehow (no log, no move, no touch, no nothing), the system restores either mirroring or both screens enabled. The whole thing is a mistery, and I'd really like to disable even the possibility of automatic display settings change.
I don't mind digging into config files, just please someone tell me how to kill this feature :)

Comment: I also added `xrandr --output LVDS --off --output VGA --auto` to file `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/98vgaonly`, still no perfect work.

Comment: Yeah, this auto display crap has me on the verge of trying other distros. I've been fighting it for years. It doesn't work very well for me and I'd rather have the old school manual controls from xorg.conf than this illusive gui-driven stuff that works just often enough to prevent me from taking action to switch... Until now...